# Avoid decimal.TryParse throwing OverflowException

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, decimal

I have a quantity field and a price field, which are both decimals. It's possible to order huge quantities and also extremely expensive stuff. The combination of both never happens in real life but that doesn't mean that a user might enter both an enormous quantity and price.

To make sure that I won't end up with a too big number in the "Total" field I'm trying to do a decimal.TryParse() but I get an OverflowException when multiplying the vales.
Does anyone have any smart idea how to avoid this?

```
decimal outvalue;
decimal qty = 10000000000000000;
decimal price = 10000000000000000;

if (!decimal.TryParse((qty * price).ToString(), out outvalue))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("myfield", "Total value is too big");
}
```

Throws:

[image: OverflowException]

Comment: That "validation" is meaningless - it performs the very operation it's trying to prevent. The `TryParse` is meaningless as well, because the result of `qty * price` is already a decimal. What's the point of converting it to a string only to parse it back to its original value?

Comment: If you are allowing users to enter their own price I doubt you will ever have this problem. That said, use exception handling, emphasis on *handling*. Just like with any bad data or invalid operation, don't do that, and then prompt the user to correct it.

Comment: A useful validation would be to check *both* inputs and reject the input if both values are too big. ASP.NET Core's validation classes can do that easily. It's also possible to use custom validation method that mark the input as invalid if they throw

Comment: `qty * price` has **already** overflow'd **before** you call `decimal.TryParse`

Comment: `TryParse` only catches exceptions which happen during parsing a string, but it didn't even start parsing when the exception is thrown. The error happens because your `qty * price` calculation goes out of the range of a decimal ...

Answer (score 3):

What don't just cast both `decimal`s to `double`, multiply them and, finally, check?

```
  //TODO: put any reasonable value instead of 1e20 
  if ((double) qty * (double) price > 1e20) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("myfield", "Total value is too big");
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Straightforward way, as @Crowcoder said, handle the overflow exception and prompt user if needed

Other way:

```
if (decimal.MaxValue / qty < price)
... sorry, wrong input
```

(not tested...)

Comment: What if `qty == 0M` and `price == 123M`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I suspect it possibly will throw an excepion. That's the _not tested_ part of the answer, meaning "should think to all possible use cases, starting from an obvious `qty == 0` "

Answer (score 2):

First, let's understand the problem with your code: The exception is raised before the TryParse is executed. If we expand your code in a fewer instructions per line, you get:

```
decimal outvalue;
decimal qty = 10000000000000000;
decimal price = 10000000000000000;
decimal total = qty * price;  // Exception raised here
string temp = total.ToString();

if (!decimal.TryParse(temp, out outvalue))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("myfield", "Total value is too big");
}
```

To fix your code, you have some options, I recomend you see [BigInterger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0). You can also see about [checked and unchecked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked-and-unchecked) arithmetic contexts.

Comment: Typo? It should have been multplication: `decimal total = qty * price;`

Comment: ops. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, I would suggest using some reasonable limits on both price and quantity. Google suggest the most expensive item is around 10^10 USD, 6 magnitudes lower than in your example. likewise, ordering more than say 10^12 of anything would be unlikely, very large quantities would probably be ordered in bulk, by weight.

The range of decimal is 10^28, so as long as your count and price are both lower than 10^13 you should be fine.